# Using a postcode range for shipping (expresso-store)

Tags: expressionengine, expresso-store

We're building a online-store/site for a winery, and they have a matrix/table of shipping costs to different regions (in Australia).

In Exp-resso Store 1.6.0, is there anyway of setting up a post-code for a specific shipping cost?

`i.e. postcode= 2000-2249, 2555-2574 = $10 + $1/kg. 1250-1263 = $12 +$1.1/kg`

Additional info: The deliveries are technically through AusPost, but using  their "Wine Delivery Service" which doesn't match their normal parcel delivery stuff, so we can't use the AusPost plugin/API :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this from the control panel. However, you can easily write your own shipping calculator using PHP.

An example of a simple custom shipping plugin is here:

https://gist.github.com/2176462

Comment: Had a feeling that might be the case, will look into making our own. Thanks for the help